# Storing Crystal Reports in XML files?

Tags: crystal-reports

I was talking to somebody a recently who mentioned it was possible to store reports created using Crystal Reports as XML files.

Upon Googling this, I can't find anything suggesting that this is the case (using *data* stored in XML in a report, yes, but actually storing the report, the part stored by default as a .rpt file, no.

Am I correct in assuming that there was in fact some sort of misunderstanding between us and it in fact not possible to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible to store the report template in XMLformat. XML is supported as export format of the "rendered" report only.
 For what purpose do you need the report template in XML format. There is a Java reporting solution called [Crystal-Clear](http://www.inetsoftware.de/products/crystalclear/) which can read the Crytsal Reports report template and save it as XML report template. The other way round this does not work. After you created a XML file you cannot open the report with Crystal Reports again. But you can work with the report using [Crystal-Clear](http://www.inetsoftware.de/products/crystalclear/) which is coming with a GUI-designer too.

Answer (score 3):

[Use the Crystal Reports SDK to convert the RPT file format to XML](http://code.google.com/p/rpttoxml/).

Comment: Another option is to use the [PsCrystal](https://github.com/craibuc/PsCrystal) PowerShell module to extract the desired properties from the file.

Answer (score 1):

There's a GitHub project that will convert [RPT to XML](https://github.com/ajryan/RptToXml). The intent of the tool is to use for diffs, so I don't know if there is a XML to RPT converter. Crystal Reports certainly can not take the XML file and open it like a .RPT file.

Answer (score 0):

At least in version 8.5 XML-file is one of the supported export destinations just like PDF, Excel or Word. Seems unlikely they'd have removed the support in later versions.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested in Crystal Reports 10.

Open up the report you want to export, click on export in the file menu, and at least in CR 10, XML is at the very bottom.

Next a screen appears, asking for directory and  base file name to save to. According to the Window it uses "Crystal Markup Language" XML Format

Comment: Thank you, but not exactly what I was looking for. I was hoping for a way to store a report in XML *before* it had any data in it, and which could then be reopened in Crystal and edited, etc. Doesn't seem like this is actually possible, so I'm just going to go with the standard .rpt files.